# Locating the initramfs partition on Android 4.4

Tags: custom-roms, android-tv

I would like to modify the init.*.rc files on an Android 4.4 TV box (rooted).

I saw many tutorials saying that i should dump the boot partition, unpack+edit file+repack and reflash it back.

I looked at the by-name directory and saw partition names like kernel, baseparam, bootargs etc, but I found that the kernel partition contains only the kernel file itself, but not the initramfs file.

Where can I locate the ram disk file?

Edit: Please find the partitions below:

```
~ # ls /dev/block/platform/hi_mci.1/by-name/ -l
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Jan  1  1970 baseparam -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p5
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Jan  1  1970 bootargs -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Jan  1  1970 cache -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p15
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Jan  1  1970 deviceinfo -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p4
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Jan  1  1970 fastboot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Jan  1  1970 fastplay -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p9
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Jan  1  1970 fastplaybak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p10
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Jan  1  1970 kernel -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p11
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Jan  1  1970 logo -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Jan  1  1970 logobak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p8
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Jan  1  1970 misc -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p12
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Jan  1  1970 pqparam -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Jan  1  1970 recovery -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Jan  1  1970 sdcard -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p16
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Jan  1  1970 system -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p13
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Jan  1  1970 userdata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p14
```

Comment: @alecxs Please find the updated question content